# c# migrating to ANTLR 4 from ANTLR 3 with AST

Tags: c#, migration, antlr, antlr4

I have inherited some c# code based on ANTLR 3. 
We have some grammar files that uses the **AST** (abstract syntax tree) option and we use those grammar to parse text files with a very odd "language" to objects. we are using the AST as intermediate objects and than convert them to the real objects that we need (with some more processing).

I have no knowledge in ANTLR but currently we have a bottleneck in the application performance from ANTLR processing of the files.
Since we are using ANTLR 3 we thought that we might get a performance boost if we migrate to ANTLR (and also get the latest and greatest version of ANTLR which is always a good practice).
I have read that AST no longer exist in ANTLR 4, what is the best (and simplest) way to replace it and what will it mean to my current code.

What is the best approach to upgrade ? and will it really give us a performance boost.

An example of one of the grammar file ( there are 6 and this is the simplest one):

```
 grammar Rules;

options
{
    language=CSharp2;
    output=AST;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
    superClass = OOPLParserBase;
}

tokens
{
    OOPL_MODEL;
}


@lexer::namespace { TestParser.Common.RulesParser }

@parser::namespace { TestParser.Common.RulesParser }

@header
{
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TestParser.OOPLModel;
}

@members
{

public RulesParser() : base(null)
{
}

protected override CommonTree GetAst()
{
    return root().Tree as CommonTree;
}

protected override Lexer GetLexer()
{
    return new RulesLexer();
}

}

//semantic analysis

root            :   header (rule_line COMMENT?)+ -> ^(header rule_line+);

header          :   header_comment+ -> ^(OOPL_MODEL<OOPLModel>[new CommonToken(OOPL_MODEL), "1.0"] header_comment+);

header_comment      :   COMMENT -> ^(COMMENT<OOPLComment>[$COMMENT, $COMMENT.Text]);

rule_line       :   parameter RULE_TYPE COMMA  PARAMETER_NAME COLON condition -> ^(RULE_TYPE<OOPLBlock>[$RULE_TYPE, $RULE_TYPE.Text] parameter PARAMETER_NAME<OOPLValue>[$PARAMETER_NAME, $PARAMETER_NAME.Text] condition);

parameter       :   PARAMETER_NAME EQUALS (integer_value = INTEGER | real_value = REAL |string_value = STRING) COMMA -> ^(PARAMETER_NAME<OOPLKeyedValue>[$PARAMETER_NAME, $PARAMETER_NAME.Text, SingleWhereNotNull<IToken>($integer_value, $string_value, $real_value).Text]);

condition       :   condition_value COMMA condition_value COMMA condition_value COMMA condition_value COMMA condition_value COMMA condition_value COMMA condition_value COMMA condition_value COMMA condition_value COMMA condition_value COMMA condition_value COMMA condition_value COMMA condition_value;

condition_value     :   (asterisk| parameter_name | positive_integer);

asterisk        :   ASTERISK -> ^(ASTERISK<OOPLValue>[$ASTERISK, $ASTERISK.Text]);

parameter_name      :   PARAMETER_NAME -> ^(PARAMETER_NAME<OOPLValue>[$PARAMETER_NAME, $PARAMETER_NAME.Text]);

positive_integer    :   INTEGER -> ^(INTEGER<OOPLValue>[$INTEGER, $INTEGER.Text]);

//lexical analysis

EQUALS          :   '=';

NEW_LINE_R      :   '\r' { $channel = HIDDEN; };

NEW_LINE_N      :   '\n' { $channel = HIDDEN; };

RULE_TYPE       :   ('Time'|'TIME'|'Lol'|'LOL'|'World'|'WORLD'|'Template'|'TEMPLATE');

DOUBLE_COLON            :       COLON COLON;

INTEGER         :   MINUS? DIGIT+;

REAL            :       INTEGER '.' INTEGER;

PARAMETER_NAME      :   ASTERISK? (LETTER|DIGIT|UNDERSCORE|FORWARDSLASH|DOUBLE_COLON|MINUS)+ ASTERISK?;


WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | NEW_LINE_R
        | NEW_LINE_N
        ) { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;

COMMENT                 :       '#' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* NEW_LINE_R? NEW_LINE_N;

STRING          :   '"'~('"')* '"';

fragment
MINUS   :   '-';

COMMA           :   ',';

COLON                   :       ':';

fragment
DOT         :   '.';


ASTERISK        :   '*';

fragment
FORWARDSLASH        :   '/';

fragment
UNDERSCORE      :   '_';

fragment
DIGIT           :   '0'..'9';   

fragment
LETTER          :   'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do the transformation solely in `C#` code after the parse.

In this case I'd even skip the intermediate AST form and transform the parse tree (provided by ANTLR4) directly into the target representation.

Some prefer ParseTreeListener/ParseTreeWalkers, which aid you in walking the parse tree. Check these out, if you want some pre-build code. Be sure to use the typed ParseTreeWalker, which should be named `RulesParseTreeListener<>`, inherit and adjust to your needs.
link: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parse+Tree+Listeners

I'd not recommend ParseTreeVisitors which are invoked during the parse (as opposed to after the parse). They are only suitable for simple operations or grammars that are not context free and require code during the parse. If the requirements evolve later on, you're way more flexible with custom processing or listeners/walkers.

Comment: The link you provided, requests login info.

Comment: @Athafoud See the historical page on Wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20150726222716/https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parse+Tree+Listeners